# R: Assigning values to data

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have data from participants in a research study. I'm trying to score their responses by assigning a value of 1 if their response is correct and 0 if it is not.

In this case, Q1 represents the responses to the first question. "Yes" is the correct response. I entered:

```
if (is.na(Q1) || Q1 == "Yes") {Q1 <- 1} else {Q1 <- 0}
```

And all of the data in Q1 was replaced with 1, just 1, nothing else, while I was expecting a set of 0s and 1s.

Could you please tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: could you please inlcude some dummy data, or an extract for your data - that will make it much easier to give you specific solution

Comment: Besides, please provide how is your output and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ifelse` :

```
ans <- ifelse(is.na(Q1) | Q1 == "Yes", 1, 0)
```

You can also do this without `ifelse` by casting the logical values to integer.

```
ans <- as.integer(is.na(Q1) | Q1 == "Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `+` to coerce the logical to binary

```
ans <- +(is.na(Q1)| Q1 == "Yes")
```